# Functional Analysis, spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

If p $\neq$ q, Show that it implies $\ell_p$ $\neq$ $\ell_q$ $\\$

I am new to functional Analysis, I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Find a sequence $(a_n)$ so that one of $\sum |a_n|^p$ and $\sum |a_n|^q$ is finite and the other infinite.

Comment: @DavidMitra  Please can you give me an example of one. I have racked my brains, since after you left the comment above. But I couldn't find anything, no headway.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another hint: $\ell_1 \not= \ell_2$ because
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1k = \infty \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2} < \infty.$$
Can you modify this example?

Comment: Not really for now, but I will study it closely. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I have tried but couldn't. Any further hint/help will be appreciated.Thanks.